# OOP PHP Login/Register System

Tags: php, mysql, oop, authentication

I'm busy with learning OOP PHP and my goal is to make a simple login/register system for users. The idea is to simply register your first name, last name and password, that would be stored into a MySQL database.

Right now i'm trying to store some data into the database, but I'm stuck.. I can't get any data stored into my database. Here is the code I'm working on:

**register.php :**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'inc/user.php';

$user = new User();

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {

  $firstname   = ($_POST['firstname']);
  $lastname = ($_POST['lastname']);
  $password = ($_POST['password']);
  $email = ($_POST['email']);

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

<title> Project Hour </title>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="logo">
  <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="login">

  <div class="form">

    <form method="POST" action="#" class="register-form">

      <input  type="text"     name="firstname"   placeholder="voornaam"/>
      <input  type="text"     name="lastname"    placeholder="achternaam"/>
      <input  type="password" name="password"    placeholder="************"/>
      <input  type="text"     name="email"       placeholder="emailadres"/>

      <button type="submit"   name="register">create</button>

      <p class="message"> Al geregistreerd? <a href="index.php"> Inloggen </a></p>

    </form>

  </div>
```

**user.php :**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'connect.php';

class User {

    private $dbase;

    public function __constructor() {

        $this->dbase = new Connect();
        $this->dbase = $this->dbase->dbConnect();

    }

    public function userRegiser($firstname, $lastname, $password, $email) {

        try {

            $st = $dbase->prepare("INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, password, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :password, :email)");

            $st->bindparam(":firstname", $firstname);
            $st->bindparam(":lastname", $lastname);
            $st->bindparam(":password", $password);
            $st->bindparam(":email", $email);

            if($st->execute()) {

                echo 'Inserted successfully.';
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            echo 'Something failed :' . $e->getMessage;
        }

    }

}


?>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php

class Connect {

    public function dbConnect() {

        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $pdo = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projecthour'; 

        try {

            $db = new PDO($pdo, $user, $pass);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            echo 'Connection failed : ' . $e->getMessage();

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Don't you forget to call `userRegister` function?

Comment: I've tried to call the function when you click the register button, so after the isset. But how can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors I see here.

**First** - when form submitted and you have user data - you should call `userRegister` method:

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $firstname   = ($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = ($_POST['lastname']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $email = ($_POST['email']);
    $user->userRegister($firstname, $lastname, $password, $email);
}
```

**Next problem** is

```
$this->dbase = $this->dbase->dbConnect();
```

So here `$this->dbase` is equals to something that is returned by `dbConnect` method. But this method returns **nothing**. But it should return PDO instance:

```
public function dbConnect() {

    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $pdo = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projecthour'; 

    try {

        $db = new PDO($pdo, $user, $pass);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

        // here, return new PDO instance
        return $db;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        echo 'Connection failed : ' . $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

**And finally**, your `userRegiser` (by the way it should be `userRegis**t**er`) method uses `$dbase`. But `$dbase` is not what you expect it to be. It's just a local variable, but you need a class property:

```
public function userRegiser($firstname, $lastname, $password, $email) {
    try {
        $st = $this->dbase->prepare("INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, password, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :password, :email)");
            // ^ here
```

**And** thanks to @RajdeepPaul: constructor definition should be:

```
public function __construct() {   // not __constructor!
```

Comment: I see, I noticed the userRegiser right away.. I will try it, thanks!

Comment: @NickMulder Your constructor method of `User` class is also wrong, it should be: `function __construct(){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {

  $firstname   = ($_POST['firstname']);
  $lastname = ($_POST['lastname']);
  $password = ($_POST['password']);
  $email = ($_POST['email']);

// call userRegiser

echo $user->userRegiser($firstname, $lastname, $password, $email);

}
```

and in User.php

```
    public function userRegiser($firstname, $lastname, $password, $email) {

            try {

                $st = $dbase->prepare("INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, password, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :password, :email)");

                $st->bindparam(":firstname", $firstname);
                $st->bindparam(":lastname", $lastname);


$st->bindparam(":password", $password);
            $st->bindparam(":email", $email);

            if($st->execute()) {

                return 'Inserted successfully.';
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            return 'Something failed :' . $e->getMessage;
        }

    }
```